# Implementing Seam Carving Method in C#

Tags: seam-carving

I would like to Scale an Image from 640x480 to 64x48. There are different approaches used by the picture manipulating programs like Gimp and Photoshop. For eg.Gimp uses liquid rescale algorithm and photoshop uses path match algorithm for better scaling. Both uses Seam Carving approach. But I am unable to compare and implement them in C#. I downloaded some example code , but it is in Matlab. Is there an efficient algorithm in C# to implement this in better way. Please provide, if any existing code for the Seam carving Implementation in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use ImageMagic since your doing C#, it will give you all kind of conversion possibilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot Orn for the Suggestion.And Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Why would you want to interface with ImageMagik? Seam carving is a pretty easy concept to understand and code.

Comment: I have done that in the past and it worked great for me.  Why don't you add answer on your own then ?  I'm sure it would help the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I've found following implementations of seam carving on C#:

- [magicarver](https://code.google.com/p/magicarver/)
- My library: [Seam-Carving-Advanced](https://github.com/KvanTTT/Seam-Carving-Advanced). GPU processing under developing. This lib is porting of C++ lib: [seam-carving-gui](https://code.google.com/p/seam-carving-gui/)